# Using Linked List as the output?

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list

I'm trying to write a bank account that asks the user if they want to see records, remove records, and other stuff. [This is what I'm trying to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atatb.png)

My program is nearly done the only problem I'm having is getting the output. I'm getting some weird error when i tried producing the output. When the output works. I'll put it inside a linked list.

```
public class Bank
{

public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<Customer> accounts = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    Customer customer1 = new Customer(1, "Savings", "Dollars", 800);
    Customer customer2 = new Customer(2, "Checking", "Euro", 1900);
    Customer customer3 = new Customer(3, "Checking", "Pound", 8000);

    accounts.add(customer1);
    accounts.add(customer2);
    accounts.add(customer3);


    int customerID=4;
    String choice;
    int deposit;
    int withdraw;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Customer operation = new Customer();
    boolean flag = true;

    String accountType;
    String currencyType;
    int balance;

    while(flag){
      System.out.println("Select a choice:");
      System.out.println("1. Existing customer");
      System.out.println("2. New customer");
      System.out.println("3. Quit");


      String input = in.next();

        //existing user
        if(input.equals("1")){

          System.out.println("Enter CustomerID: ");
          customerID = in.nextInt();


          System.out.println("Would you like to: ");
          System.out.println("1. Deposit ");
          System.out.println("2. Withdraw ");
          System.out.println("3. Display account info ");
          System.out.println("4. Check balance ");

          choice = in.next();

          if(choice.equals("1")){
            System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
            deposit = in.nextInt();
            operation.deposit(deposit);
          }

          else if (choice.equals("2")){
           System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
            withdraw = in.nextInt();
            operation.withdraw(withdraw);

          }

          else if (choice.equals("3")){
            operation.display(accounts.get(customerID));
          }

          else if (choice.equals("4"))
            operation.balance(accounts.get(customerID));

          else
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }

        //new user
         else if(input.equals("2")){
          //add new user to arraylist

           int newID = customerID + 1;

           System.out.println("Enter account type: ");
           accountType = in.next();
           System.out.println("Enter currency type: ");
           currencyType = in.next();
           System.out.println("Enter initial balance: ");
           balance = in.nextInt();

           System.out.println("Your customer ID will be: " + newID);


           accounts.add(new Customer(newID, accountType, currencyType, balance));


        }

        else if(input.equals("3")){

          System.out.println("Thanks for using this bank!");
          flag = false;
        }


        else{

          System.out.println("Invalid");

        }
      }

    }
}
```

My second class:

```
 public class Customer 
{

String accountType, currencyType, info;
public int customerID, balance, amount;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


public Customer(int customerID, String accountType, String currencyType, int balance)
{
    this.accountType = accountType;
    this.currencyType = currencyType;
    this.customerID = customerID;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Customer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public int deposit(int amount){

    amount = input.nextInt();
    if (amount >= 500) {
      System.out.println("Invalid");

    }
    else{
      balance = balance + amount;

    }
    return balance;
}

public int withdraw(int amount){

    if (balance < amount) {
      System.out.println("Invalid amount.");
    }
    else if (amount >= 500) {
      System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
    else {
      balance = balance - amount;

    }
    return balance;
}


public void display(ArrayList<Customer> accounts)
{
    System.out.println("CustomerID:" + accounts.customerID);
    System.out.println("Account Type:" + accounts.accountType);
    System.out.println("Currency Type: " + accounts.currencyType);
    System.out.println("Balance:" + accounts.balance);

}

public void balance(ArrayList<Customer> accounts) {
    System.out.println("Balance:" + accounts.balance);
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error you encountered when running the application. Better post  the stacktrace of it

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList` won't have properties or methods such as `customerID`, `accountType`, etc.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class count.Numbers1

Comment: Check your command line. No class named `Numbers1` is disclosed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.util.ArrayList won't have properties or methods such as `customerID`, `accountType`, `currencyType` and `balance`.

I guess your methods `display()` and `balance()` shoudn't take any arguments and should use the properties of the instance to print.

```
public void display()
{
    System.out.println("CustomerID:" + customerID);
    System.out.println("Account Type:" + accountType);
    System.out.println("Currency Type: " + currencyType);
    System.out.println("Balance:" + balance);

}

public void balance() {
    System.out.println("Balance:" + balance);
}
```

Then, these lines

```
operation.display(accounts.get(customerID));
operation.balance(accounts.get(customerID));
```

should be

```
accounts.get(customerID).display();
accounts.get(customerID).balance();
```

There seems many more things to be corrected -- for example, usage of `withdraw()`.

Comment: Thanks that fixed most of it. For some reason it's still not printing

Comment: Thanks that fixed most of it. The only problem is when I try running it and press 3 and enter a customer ID it gives me a huge error.